# Send ActiveStorage File to User Via Custom Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am aware of the ActiveStorage `url_for(user.avatar)` method. Example:

```
<%= link_to "Download this file", url_for(@user.avatar) %>
```

This is great, but it appears like it has no authorization built around it.  Anyone with this link can download this document.

In the past when I used [paperclip](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip), I had a link that went to a custom controller action. That custom controller action did authorization, and if all is good, then I used `send_file` to send the file to the user. It was something like this:

```
def deliver_the_file
  authorize :my_authorization
  send_file @user.avatar.path
end
```

How can I do this with active_storage?  All I have gotten to work is the `url_for` implementation which does not authorize the user at all.

I am looking specifically at the [Download Files](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) part of the Rails Guides on ActiveStorage.

Relevant example code:

```
# model 
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :book_cover
end


class BooksController < ApplicationController
 ... 

  # custom action to authorize and then deliver the active_storage file
  def deliver_it
    # ... assume authorization already happened
    send_file rails_blob_path(@book.book_cover, disposition: "attachment")
  end
end
```

This errors out and says:

> Cannot read file

I also attempted this:

```
def deliver_it
  # ... assume authorization already happened
  send_file @book.book_cover.download
end
```

This returned the error:

> string contains null byte

And I also attempted this:

```
def deliver_it
  @book.book_cover.download
end
```

This returned the error:

> BooksController#deliver_it is missing a template for this request

I have also tried this:

```
def deliver_it
  send_file @book.book_cover.blob
end
```

This errors out and says:

> no implicit conversion of ActiveStorage::Blob into String

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `ActiveStorage::Blob#service_url` to redirect to a signed, short-lived URL for the blob:

```
class Books::CoversController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_active_storage_host, :set_book

  def show
    redirect_to @book.cover.service_url
  end

  private
    def set_active_storage_host
      ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
    end

    def set_book
      @book = Current.person.books.find(params[:book_id])
    end
end
```

Alternatively, serve the file yourself. You can use `ActionController::Live` to stream the file to the client instead of reading the entire file into memory at once.

```
class Books::CoversController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  before_action :set_book

  def show
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = @book.cover.content_type
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; #{@book.cover.filename.parameters}"

    @book.cover.download do |chunk|
      response.stream.write(chunk)
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I did happen to see your `service_url` suggestion, but it came up with an error for me:  "Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true"

Comment: Sorry, @Neil! I updated the first example to demonstrate setting `ActiveStorage::Current.host` as the disk service requires.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One more question: is there a way to set how long the link is active for?  Perhaps setting it to only 30 seconds?

Comment: @Neil: yes, you can pass `expires_in: 30.seconds` to `service_url`.

Comment: The stream solution was the only thing that worked for me.  Just an FYI - you are missing the `begin` statement at the opening of the method.  Thank you!

Comment: Great answer. Just one gotcha: `ActionController::Live` doesn't play well with `Devise`. If your app crashes with `ArgumentError (uncaught throw :warden):` for unauthenticated users, you'll have to wrap your routes in a `authenticate :user do … end` block. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2332) that's been reported since 2013!

Answer (score 15):

I derived this solution from a comment on [this ActiveStorage issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31676)

```
def deliver_it
  send_data @book.book_cover.download, filename: @book.book_cover.filename.to_s, content_type: @book.book_cover.content_type
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I used `redirect_to` here and it worked:

```
redirect_to rails_blob_path(@book.book_cover, disposition: "attachment")
```

Comment: this changes the URL in my case, but remains on the same page. A "reload" of the page, would cause the download to be triggered instead of the page to be reload.
The simplest solution would be to set `target:="_blank"` so this happens in a new tab, that will get closed afterwards.